# Why are https downloads pausing with PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY?

Tags: android, https, android-download-manager

I'm using the [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#STATUS_PAUSED) service in Android to download files over https URLs, such as https://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/pdf/sample-link_1.pdf. The files are not (currently) password protected, in case that makes any difference.

Once I enqueue a download request, the DownloadManager starts the download, but it seems to hang. When I check the status, I get

```
COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR: 0
COLUMN_STATUS: 4
COLUMN_REASON: 1
```

COLUMN_STATUS 4 is [STATUS_PAUSED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#STATUS_PAUSED), "when the download is waiting to retry or resume."

COLUMN_REASON 1 is [PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY), "when the download is paused because some **network error occurred** and the download manager is waiting before retrying the request." But there doesn't seem to be a way to determine **what network error occurred**. The download never successfully completes.

I've checked the logcat monitor for related warnings and errors, but found nothing.

I've tried this with multiple different servers, both in-house and public, with the same result.

There is no obvious network problem: the Wi-Fi connection is up, and downloads **using http:// work just fine**: the file is downloaded promptly and appears in the filesystem at the specified destination.

In the case of https downloads, our server logs show that the files **are being successfully served** from the server's point of view. Testing the same https URLs in a **browser** on a laptop result in successful download of the files, without any obvious problems or extra negotiations showing up in the developer tools network panel.

My code (summarized):

```
sManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(sourceURI);
final Uri destinationUri = Uri.fromFile(destinationFile);
req.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
            | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
        .setDestinationUri(destinationUri)
        .setMimeType(...);

long id = sManager.enqueue(req);
```

Summary: An https download started via DownloadManager hangs indefinitely, while the same https download works fine in a browser, and plain http downloads work fine with the same app using DownloadManager. The best clue I have is that `PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY` indicates "some network error occurred." How can I determine what the network error is?

Comment: Are you sure the SSL certificate of the URL is issued by a CA which is trusted by Android?

Comment: On stock Android, the component that actually does the downloading [appears to use `HttpURLConnection`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/downloads/DownloadThread.java). You might toss together a quick-and-dirty app using `HttpURLConnection` (or modify [one of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.1/Service/Downloader)) and see what you get. I agree with Prerak, that this feels like an SSL handshake issue.

Comment: @PrerakSola: Good question. I'll look into it.

Comment: @PrerakSola: In both the example URL given above and on our in-house server, the root CA is AddTrust External CA Root, which is listed in my device's trusted credentials. The intermediate CAs are different... not sure if that matters...

Comment: @CommonsWare: Good idea. I did that, and got a `CertificateException: CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.` So ... I'm not sure what that means, given that the root CA for each site is a CA that's on the device's trusted list.

Comment: "I'm not sure what that means, given that the root CA for each site is a CA that's on the device's trusted list" -- how are you determining this? Browsers may have their own CA list, rather than go with some platform set (which, for all I know, might only be available to Java-based apps anyway).

Comment: @CommonsWare: In both the antennahouse.com URL given above and on our in-house server, the root CA is AddTrust External CA Root, which is listed in my device's trusted credentials under Settings > Security > Trusted credentials. Now I'm looking at https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#MissingCa to try and figure out if there's a missing intermediate CA causing the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proximate cause seems to be a CertificateException: CertPathValidatorException: `Trust anchor for certification path not found.` I found this out by [using an HttpURLConnection directly](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.1/Service/Downloader) (thanks to @CommonsWare for the suggestion) instead of the DownloadManager, which gave more direct access to exceptions. (This was true in the case of our in-house server. It does not seem to be the case with the sample URL I mentioned, which seemed to be having the same problem with DownloadManager ... but maybe that same problem had a different cause.)

The root CA (in all cases) is "AddTrust External CA Root", which is present in the list of trusted CAs on the device, under Settings > Security > Trusted credentials. So if this is a trusted CA root, why is there a "Trust anchor for certification path not found" exception?

It looks like there is an intermediate CA not being included in the chain served by the server, as [described here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#MissingCa). In fact, using `openssl s_client -connect` to check the CA chain confirms that the intermediate CA's are not included. The [Android doc article](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#MissingCa) suggests two possible solutions: include the intermediate CA's in the server chain, or explicitly trust them in the app by creating a special TrustManager. I hope to do the former.

Comment: P.S. The diagnosis and the fix (include intermediate CA's in the served certificate chain) are confirmed. After making that change on the server, the problem has disappeared.