# DownloadManager not working on android 8.0

Tags: android, android-download-manager

DownloadManager does not work on Android 8.0. I don't know why. Can somebody help me?

This is what I have tried:

```
val downloadBroadcastReceiver = DownloadBroadcastReceiver()
context.registerReceiver(downloadBroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(folder + File.separator + fileName))
request.setMimeType(mimeType)
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)
request.setTitle(title)
request.setDescription(description)
request.setNotificationVisibility(VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
id = downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/48130822/1333975

Comment: @Ahmad doesn't apply. In that question the OP's problem is that he sets `DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI` whereas here is not the case.

Comment: I have same problem.

Comment: same for me. Help me please

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any VPN applications enabled on the phone. In my case I had an ad-blocker application hat ran as VPN on the phone that interfered with the DownloadManager.

Answer (score 0):

You can narrow down the type of problem you are having by checking the status inside of DownloadManager. If the download isn't starting, then it is probably paused.

```
 try (Cursor cursor = manager.query(query)) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int statusColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    int downloadStatus = cursor.getInt(statusColumn);
                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED == downloadStatus) {
                        int reasonColumn =   cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
                        int reasonCode = cursor.getInt(reasonColumn);
                        Log.e(TAG, "Download paused: " + reasonCode);
                    } else if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == downloadStatus
                            || DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED == downloadStatus) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Download Ended");
                    }
}
```

From there, the problem depends on what you're seeing in the above block, but here are some common cases you could be having:

If your url is using https://, you might be having this problem - [Why are https downloads pausing with PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41430496/why-are-https-downloads-pausing-with-paused-waiting-to-retry)

If you're url is using http:// but not on Android 9, you could be seeing this: [Cleartext HTTP traffic to 192.168.1.2 not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334686/cleartext-http-traffic-to-192-168-1-2-not-permitted)

If your url is it http:// over Android 9, you're seeing this: [How to solve Android P DownloadManager stopping with "Cleartext HTTP traffic to 127.0.0.1 not permitted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770323/how-to-solve-android-p-downloadmanager-stopping-with-cleartext-http-traffic-to) 
Which unfortunately is caused by this google bug - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114143692 . And the only way around that is to provide a https: alternative.