# Cleartext HTTP traffic to 192.168.1.2 not permitted

Tags: http, android-studio, https

```
String login_url = "http://192.168.1.2/login.php";   
URL url = new URL(login_url");
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = 
(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
....
```

I want to send a request to wampserver but Android Studio stops the execution with that message on the title. What is wrong? I just updated my Android Studio to the latest version (P). That wasn't an error before and I could work properly... How can I fix this?